# 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GenericTypeArguments'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

As  the `GenericTypeArguments` property was added in .NET 4.5

Is there any way or alternative for this method in .Net 4.0

In my current project I can't use .Net version 4.5.

I want to try [this technique](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EntityJustWorksSQL-Data-b66af376#content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a method [`Type.GetGenericTypeArguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx) that has been available for ages. I suspect that at least in *most* cases, the two are equivalent. I suspect that the property is just part of the reflection API design in .NET 4.5 (to use `TypeInfo` etc).

Comment: Dang, was just going to say this :D

Comment: The property internally calls this method, so it's equivalent.